# Search not working on brand new server

Tags: 2013, search

This is a brand new server with June 2016 CU installed. RAM is 8GB. This is a two server farm where DB is stored on separate server.

Search service is up and running.

I just created a new search service application. After creation it was giving me some error "admin component is not running" in search service application in CA so I followed a Microsoft tutorial (forgot the link) which said to change setting in IIS. This fixed the issue and I was able to start crawl.

After crawling is finished, when I try to search something then I get following error:

> Culture_Client::Constructing CultureInfo from '-1' failed:
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Positive number required. 
>   Parameter name: culture

Additionally I also get following error in logs:

> Error occured: System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException: The HTTP
>   service located at
>   http://myserver:32843/cbc85e69ab334e90bd775d0282edce40/SearchService.svc
>   is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or
>   because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address.
>   Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the
>   service again later. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

I also get this above error when I try to access any of the following links in Site Collection Settings.

Search Result Sources
Search Result Types
Search Query Rules

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: 8GB is a very small amount of RAM to be running all services in. Try increasing the amount of RAM available to at least 16GB and try again. I have seen this sort of error when the system doesn't have enough resources and some services cannot run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the application pool for the search service either having problems starting or having the wrong credentials for whichever account it's using. Another thing to check is the search server account.

Comment: SharePoint Web Services Root application pool was stopped. Although it is not normally used but since I changed my search admin and search services to use this one (that first tutorial I am talking about above) hence I needed to start it.